# Image link does not href to proper page in multilingual site

Tags: 7, navigation, i18n-l10n

I am honing my Drupal skills by developing a small website: [www.find-word.com](http://www.find-word.com). It is multilingual with English and French enabled.

On the top right of the screen, I have two flags. The French flag is a link to the French page, but when I click on it, it displays the English page.

I checked with FireBug, and the `href` is correct:

[image]

When I type the full French URL in my browser, it is converted into the English one.

I have no idea what's happening. Does anyone know what is causing this? Does anyone have ideas, suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It is late here, so I'll read answers tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your multilingual detection settings may be configured incorrectly.

On /admin/config/regional/language/configure, make sure `URL` is at the top of the list and enabled.